# ASP.NET MVC2 IoC: Looking for an example using CastleWindsor container that works with minimum config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I am looking for an example of how to configure an ASP.NET MVC2 project to use CastleWindsor container to do IoC.

I keep running into problems setting it up, and for every problem there seems to be a solution on-line, but in the end I make so many changes and end up with such a verbose setup to get IoC working using CastleWindsor, that I thought it best to ask this question.

I am looking for the minimum configuration required in the Global.asax page, the Web.config, and if required, what other changes and extension classes are required.

I am not looking to inject into actionfilters at this stage, so just the basics. Preferably not using XML files, but doing it in .NET programatically.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is as basic as it gets:

1. Start a MVC2 project from VS2010
2. [Download MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Download) for MVC2 (the one that says "extra binaries")
3. In your project, add a reference to (all these DLLs are included in MvcContrib):

   - Castle.Core.dll
   - Castle.DynamicProxy2.dll
   - Castle.MicroKernel.dll
   - Castle.Windsor.dll
   - MvcContrib.dll
   - MvcContrib.Castle.dll
4. In your Application_Start(), add these lines (and whatever namespaces are needed):

   ```
   var container = new WindsorContainer();
   container.RegisterControllers(typeof(HomeController).Assembly);
   ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorControllerFactory(container));
   ```

Comment: I should note that currently MvcContrib includes Windsor 2.0 while the  latest version of Windsor is 2.5

Comment: Also, MvcContrib dropped support of IoC containers for MVC3